# Microsoft Access - Override Maximum Font Size?

Tags: ms-access, vba

Have a Access 2007 database which needs to have a report that prints out some really big numbers (for some signage).  Currently in Excel the template uses a 400 point font size.  When trying to change the font size in Access the following error message appears:

> The setting of the FontSize property must be from 1 through 127

I tried adding some VBA code:

```
Me.Text0.FontSize = 400
```

But this results in the same error message.

Is there anyway to programmatically override the font limitation?  Or is it so hardcoded into Access that it can't be bypassed?

Comment: Why not just use a sane font size and then scale it up after it's generated?

Comment: what do you mean by "scale it up"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm... I'd use a litle automation and send the output not to an Access Report, but to a Word document.  Then you'd not have the font size limitation.

Don't try and make Access do something it can't do, find something that can do it, and have Access ask it to do it!

Comment: Thanks - 127pt seems a little arbitary - we will need to look at using an Excel template (possibly linked to Access) in order to accomplish this.

Comment: Arbitrary? Looks like 0-based 2^7 to me. That is, it looks like the value is stored in Access as a 7-bit number and thus can't exceed 127 points. When Access was created, that was probably a reasonable limit. I'm not so sure it's horridly unreasonable even now. It's certainly not arbitrary.